# is it possible to read strings form right to left in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab

Consider the next two scripts:

```
str1='N.KABALA.150.5.L12.5'
str2='N.C.CL.15.N12.5'
```

I want to store the last part of these strings (i.e. 'L12.5' and 'N12.5')

I have already tried the following `regexp` command :

```
str1(regexp(str1,'L\d'):end)
```

but it is case sensitive (i.e. depends on the letter "L")
this wouldn't work for `str2` (the relevant letter is "N")

I would thought to read the string from right to left, instead.

is this possible in matlab ?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with reading direction. Look at the manual of `regexp` it explains how to extract strings.

Comment: Btw: *case sensitive* means that it distinguishes between upper and lower case, e.g. 'l' being different from 'L', not altogether different characters.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab does have a fliplr function to flip an array.

```
>> fliplr(str1)

ans =

5.21L.5.051.ALABAK.N

>> fliplr(str2)

ans =

5.21N.51.LC.C.N
```

Also, if it is always the last 5 characters you are after, you can use end-indexing:

```
>> str1(end-4:end)

ans =

L12.5

>> str2(end-4:end)

ans =

N12.5
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the indices of the `.` character and get the string from the second to last `.` to the end of the string:

```
str1 = 'N.KABALA.150.5.L12.5';
I = regexp(str1, '\.');
str1( I(end-1)+1:end )

>> ans = L12.5


str2 = 'N.C.CL.15.N12.5';
I = regexp(str2, '\.');
str2( I(end-1)+1:end )

>> ans = N12.5
```

Comment: good answer, but what if the last digits are integers (i.e. str3='K.CV.12.5.F8') ?

Comment: I think you should specify the exact schema/format of your strings in your post. It is hard to parse strings with unknown requirements. Are there other possibilities like `str3`?

Comment: It would pull out 5.F8 - this solution is splitting up your string based on the decimal point and extracting any string after the penultimate decimal point. Your example in this comment differs slightly as you now only have 4 decimal points in the string rather than five in the original question. I'd have used textscan with the delimiter set as the decimal point, but this does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression matches every number with or without decimal point that is preceded by a lower case or upper case letter and is at the end of the string under test.

```
str1='N.ELBETI.150.L10';
str2='N.C.CL.15.N12.5';

expr = '[a-zA-Z](\d+\.?\d?)$';
sut = str2; % string under test

[s,e,t, m] = regexp(sut,expr);
% The matched string:
m
% Only the number:
pos = t{1};
num1 = str2double(sut(pos(1,1):pos(1,2)))
```

Comment: gives 12.500 not N12.5

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. I've updated my answer.